# Fill up an input text after 2 other input boxes were filled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that contains the following columns: **size, width, length** which are all input texts (the last one, length, is disabled).
I want to insert the division width/size into length once the user fills up these 2 fields. I don't know how to do it and would like to get help!

I created them as follows:

```
<td class="ClearDataTD"><input type="text" name="WIDTH__m$memIdx"        value=""   maxlength="5"   size="5"    class="ClearInput" onKeypress="var k = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.which ; return /^([\b0-9])\$/.test(String.fromCharCode(k));"></td>
<td class="ClearDataTD"><input type="text" name="SIZE__m$memIdx"         value=""   maxlength="5"   size="5"    class="ClearInput" onKeypress="var k = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.which ; return /^([\b0-9])\$/.test(String.fromCharCode(k));"></td>
<td class="ClearDataTD"><input type="text" name="LENGTH__m$memIdx"       value=""   maxlength="5"   size="5"    class="ClearInput" disabled="disabled"></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried to solve this.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi - I'm new to Javascript.. I didn't know how to even start...

Answer (score 1):

You can check from the JavaScript, something like: "When WIDTH__m$memIdx and SIZE__m$memIdx has values, then LENGTH__m$memIdx.value = WIDTH__m$memIdx/SIZE__m$memIdx.

```
function fillLength() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width");
    var size = document.getElementById("size");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");
    if(width.value && size.value) {
        length.value = width.value/size.value
    }
}
```

You want to call this function on `focusout` event. And probably you want to add few checks: if size is not a zero etc.

Comment: First, thank you very much! Just a few questions: 1. in the 'getElementById' function, should I send them with their real names - WIDTH__m$memIdx, SIZE__m$memIdx, LENGTH__m$memIdx?  2. Should I call this function on both width and size? And when - once they are filled up? THANKS!

Comment: 1. Exactly as you wrote, you should add their real names. 2. You should call this function on "focusout" event. Try to Google something like 'focusout event input'. You do not need to control if two fields are filled up, "if" condition it the fiction does that.

Comment: Could I ask you to click on the "tick" near my answer and accept it? It will help me to grow on the platform. Thank you!